# How to use a variable with a file path in batch?

Tags: batch-file, scripting

I wrote a batch script to open some pdf files which works just fine.

However I have to often change the path for the directory. So I tried to use a variable which expands to the path of that directory.

But when I use that variable in the `for`, and in the `start` command, the script opens non-existent files.

My best guess is that the `set` command does not support the path `\`, but if someone knows a way to use the variable in the script it would be appreciated.

The code goes like this:

```bash
for /f "usebackq delims=|" %%f in (`dir /b "C:\path to the folder"`) do (
        start msedge.exe "C:\path to the folder\%%f\generic file name"
)
```

When I use the path it works just fine, but when I change it to a variable, it doesn't work.

The code with the variable goes like this:

```bash
set dirPath=C:\users\path_to_the_folder

for /f "usebackq delims=|" %%f in (`dir /b "dirPath"`) do (
        start msedge.exe "dirPath"
)
```

I tried removing the "" but when i use a variable the script opens file that doesn't exist

Comment: Drag and drop your directory onto a batch file with this content: ```@For %%G In ("%~1\*.pdf") Do @Start "" "%ProgramFiles(x86)%\Microsoft\Edge\Application\msedge.exe" "%%G"```.

Comment: Please `edit` your question to show us your attempt to `use a variable` and how you are setting that variable.

Comment: When you refer to the batch variable `dirpath`, you need to enclose the variablename in `%` to tell `cmd` that it's the value of the variable that's needed, so `'dir /b "%dirPath%"'` (note single straight quotes - and remove the `usebackq`. You'd probably also best add `/a-d` to the `dir` command to not list any subdirectory names. With the `start` command, `start "" msedge,exe "%dirpath%\%%f"` to add the filename to the directoryname for each instance of `msedge` started. Do not omit the empty pair of double-quotes which `start` uses as a window title (or use `"%%f"`)

Answer (score 0):

MS Edge expects a URL as an argument thus the command for a folder will be  as mentioned in comments One of

"%ProgramFiles%\Microsoft\Edge\Application\msedge.exe" "%~1"
"%ProgramFiles(x86)%\Microsoft\Edge\Application\msedge.exe" "%~1"

where "%~1" can be one of many types such as folder or file
NOTE URLs need forward slashes to work correctly. However Windows will do a conversion.

"file:///%UserProfile%/Desktop/"  or could be "C:\Users\username\Desktop"

If you wish to use a batch file as per question, which as defined seems very odd to call multiple user root folder. Since there are many inappropriate files unsuited to MSedge. I have currently 27 objects in a basic never used account and would not want all those in MSedge.! (I keep having to close lots of errored tabs). This feels like totally the wrong command for whatever the unstated task is.

So beware using this as it tries to open everything in the target.

```
set "dirPath=C:\users\path_to_the_folder"

REM The following is recommended but will vary depending on OS location
REM however in this usage case may not be needed see REM below
set "msedge=%ProgramFiles%\Microsoft\Edge\Application\msedge.exe"

for /f "usebackq delims=|" %%f in (`dir /b "%dirPath%"`) do (
        start "WindowName" "%msedge%" "%dirPath%\%%f"
REM the following will also work where windows uses a shorter start command
REM     start msedge "%dirPath%\%%f"
)
pause
```

Result is 10 tabs one for each  of

```
2015-11-17  13:38    <DIR>          Contacts
2019-08-14  01:50    <DIR>          Desktop
2020-08-04  17:43    <DIR>          Documents
2015-11-17  13:38    <DIR>          Downloads
2018-05-23  12:34    <DIR>          Favorites
2019-08-14  01:50    <DIR>          Links
2020-08-04  17:43    <DIR>          Music
2020-08-04  17:43    <DIR>          Pictures
2015-11-17  13:38    <DIR>          Saved Games
2020-08-04  17:43    <DIR>          Videos
```

Your stated desire is just PDF files so reduce the command down to just those objects which could be

```
in (`dir /b "%dirPath%\*.pdf"`)
```

### However it would be simpler to trim down to

```
set "dirPath=C:\users\path_to_the_folder"
forfiles /p "%dirPath%" /m *.pdf /C "cmd /r start msedge @path"
```

or simpler  yet:-

`forfiles /p "C:\users\path_to_the_folder" /m *.pdf /C "cmd /r start msedge @path"`

Bonus use that as a shortcut in this form

`%comspec% /r forfiles  /m *.pdf /C "cmd /r start msedge @path" /p`

then drop a folder on that shortcut
[image]
or use as a SendTo (place in the folder you get from key in `Win + R` then type `shell:sendto`)
[image]